# Как сгенерировать индивидуальный пароль для каждого сервера с помощью Ansible

Tags: python-2.x, ansible, root, password, generate

Привет, есть n-ое количество серверов, нужно на всех серверах поменять root пароли, так чтоб у каждого сервера он был индивидуален. А все пароли записать в 1 файл с указанием какой пароль к какому серверу относится, файл должен быть один и лежать на машине с Ansiblom.

Первая проблема с которой столнулся как сгенерить пароль, желательно силами Ansible. На базе знаний нашел такую строчку.

```
python -c "from passlib.hash import sha512_crypt; import getpass; print sha512_crypt.using(rounds=5000).hash(getpass.getpass())"
```

Но она не работает, ругается на невалидный параметр:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 
AttributeError: type object 'sha512_crypt' has no attribute 'using'
```

Можно конечно генерить пароль на стороне серверов, но тогда отпадает вся автоматизация. всё равно придётся "руками" забирать новый пароль с сервера.

Comment: Сгенерировать пароль это создать строку из нескольких случайных символов - элементарная задача, для которой в гугле куча решений, не?

Comment: @andreymal Пароль нужно генерить на стороне Ansible и передавать удалённым хостам, передавать обязательно нужно не пароль в открытом виде, а его хэш.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужен именно один файл – вам придется что-то изобретать. Например, сгенерировать csv-файл отдельной таской и затем использовать [csv-lookup](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_lookups.html#the-csv-file-lookup).

«Из коробки» у Ansible есть lookup-плагин [password](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_lookups.html#the-password-lookup), который в вашем случае можно использовать примерно так:

```
{{ lookup('password', 'creds/' + inventory_hostname + '.pwd length=15') }}
```

Значение этого выражения будет прочитано из файла `creds/<inventory_hostname>.pwd`, если он есть; или сгенерирован новый пароль и записан в соответсвующий файл, если файла нет.

Таким образом в папке `creds/` будут отдельные файлы с именами хостов. В каждом файле будет свой пароль для хоста.